# Storing a file in a hash - Only stores first line?

Tags: perl, hash

I am trying to read a file and store it into a hash.  When i print out the contents of the hash only the first line from the file stores.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

local $/ = "";
my %parameters;


open(my $PARAMS, 'SimParams.conf')
    or die "Unable to open file, $!";


while(<$PARAMS>) {
       my @temp = split(/:\s*|\n/);
       $parameters{$temp[0]} = $temp[1];
  }




dd(\%parameters);

exit 0
```

The dd(\%parameters) shows only the first line of the file as key and value. How can I get all 3 lines to be Key and Value pairings in this hash?

EDIT:  SimParams file as requested:

```
RamSize: 1000
PageSize: 200, 200
SysClock: 1
```

The datadump gives the output:

```
{ RamSize => "1000\r" }
```

Comment: Show us your SimParams.conf file content

Comment: @texasbruce I have added it to the main post but I will also include it here.  The file is only 3 lines: 

`RamSize: 1000
PageSize: 200, 200
SysClock: 1
`

Comment: Minor point, but you probably want to add a `chomp` in your while loop to get rid of line endings, otherwise you might get some unexpected output when working with the hash contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `$/` to the null string enables *paragraph mode*. Each time you read from `$PARAMS` (which should be `$params` because it is a local variable) you will be given the next block of data until a blank line is encountered

It looks like there are no blank lines in your data, so the read will return the entire contents of the file

You don't say why you modified the value of `$/`, but it looks like just removing that assignment will get your code working properly

Comment: I set $/ to null because earlier in the file I store a block of jobs which are separated into 3 blocks of 4 lines into an array of hashes.  Is there a workaround to fix this issue and keep $/ set?

Comment: You should check for blank lines in your code instead of relying on the record separator to do it for you. Also, it looks like your program is running on a Linux platform reading a file that comes from Windows. You should open it using the `:crlf` layer with `open my $params, '<:crlf', 'SimParams.conf'`

Comment: @SilentUK: Another way would be to assign the `split` directly to the hash. `%parameters = split /:\s*|\R/` will give you what you want as well as removing the spurious carriage-return

Answer (score 3):

The line

`local $/ = "";`

is reading your 3 line file as 1 chunk, the entire file. If you eliminate that code, your hash should be created.

You should probably chomp your input to remove the newline . Place it in your code before splitting to `@temp`.

`chomp;`

Borodin best explains what `local $/ = "";` does.

Comment: I need the local $/ line because earlier in my program i store a block of jobs into an array of hashes.  Is there a way to get this to read line by line without removing that line?

Comment: Setting `$/` carries a strong implication that the whole of the input file is formatted in the same way

Comment: @Borodin Yes, reading his comment to you, I see that he wants to read in chunks in some areas of his file and then later line by line. I thought he had 2 separate files. My mistake.

Comment: @ChrisCharley it is two separate files being read and stored.  One is in chunks and one is not.